# Django Rest Framework: Are there any Date based archive views like Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to get a Json with Month based archives.

I saw https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/#montharchiveview for Django. Is there any thing similar in rest framework

Answer (score 0):

I have written a python package that implements some feature of the Django archive view.

You can install it with pip:

```
pip install djangorestframework-date-archive
```

The docs are available at:
https://github.com/PJCampi/django-rest-framework-date-archive

Comment: could you add some example how to use  djangorestframework-date-archive package? after adding the routers, how to access the archives?

Comment: Fair point. I have added a bit more info about that at the in the docs of the GitHub page. But to summarise, in the context of a blog, you can just call blogs\archive\2018 to get all entries of 2018 and blogs\archive\2018\10\10 to get all entries for that day.